# Changing Annotation Image on Maps with Mapbox

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, annotations, mapbox

Within my application I need to have four different annotation images that signify differing location types. I have looked through and have found some information on this topic, however not related to Mapbox.

Currently, the user is able to filter through the differing types of locations. This is because within my database, annotations are distinguished by type within [Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PCGw.png) . Type: 1 = Skateparks, Type: 2 = Street Skating etc.

Through reading information on stack overflow I believe I need to create a custom annotation, which I have done.

```
class SkateAnnotation: MGLPointAnnotation {

var canEdit = false
var id: String!
var type: SkateType!

}
```

And I have applied the type to my annotation.

```
  func addAnnotation(park: Skatepark) {

    let point = SkateAnnotation()

    point.coordinate = park.coordinate

    point.title = park.name

    point.id = park.id

    point.subtitle = park.subtitle

    point.canEdit = park.editable

    point.type = park.type

    mapView.addAnnotation(point)

    mapView.selectAnnotation(point, animated: true)

}
```

The only part I am getting confused upon is applying these types to different images. Currently my code looks like this, which just applies one image to all annotations.

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {




 //   return nil

    var annotationImage = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: "SkateAnnotation1")

    if annotationImage == nil {

        var image = UIImage(named: "SkateAnnotation1")!




        image = image.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: image.size.height / 2, right: 0))

        annotationImage = MGLAnnotationImage(image: image, reuseIdentifier: "SkateAnnotation1")



    }

    return annotationImage

}

}
```

Is anybody able to help with setting images to annotation by their type?

My filter annotation code:

```
  func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(_ index: Int) {

   mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations!)

    for park in skateparks {

        if index == 0 {
            addAnnotation(park: park)


        }

        if index == 1 && park.type == .park {
            addAnnotation(park: park)


        }

        if index == 2 && park.type == .street {
            addAnnotation(park: park)

        }

        //Change this to feature the users own personal spots they saved to firebase

        if index == 3 && park.type == .own {
            addAnnotation(park: park)

        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my app I have two different annotations with different images for each: - CameraNotation and NoteAnnotation. I subclass MGLAnnotation for each like this:

```
// MGLAnnotation protocol reimplementation
class NoteAnnotation: NSObject, MGLAnnotation {

// As a reimplementation of the MGLAnnotation protocol, we have to add mutable coordinate and (sub)title properties ourselves.
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var title: String?
var subtitle: String?

// Custom properties that we will use to customize the annotation.
var image: UIImage?
var reuseIdentifier: String?
var uuid: String?

init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String?, subtitle: String?) {
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle

    self.reuseIdentifier = "noteAnnotation"
}
}
```

Notice the reuseIdentifier. Set a new one for each of your annotation types. Then in your viewController you can check for each like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
    // We're not concerned with the user annotation.
    guard annotation is CameraAnnotation || annotation is NoteAnnotation else {
        return nil
    }

    // For better performance, reuse existing annotations. To use multiple different annotation views, change the reuse identifier for each.
    if annotation is CameraAnnotation {
        if let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "cameraAnnotation") {
            return annotationView
        } else {
            return DraggableAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: "cameraAnnotation", size: CGSize(width: 39, height: 39), annotation: annotation)
        }
    } else if annotation is NoteAnnotation {
        if let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "noteAnnotation") {
            return annotationView
        } else {
            return DraggableAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: "noteAnnotation", size: CGSize(width: 39, height: 39), annotation: annotation)
        }
    }  else {
        return DraggableAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: "draggablePoint", size: CGSize(width: 39, height: 39), annotation: annotation)
    }
}
```

My points are draggable hence the DraggableAnnotationView calls but you go your own way. Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay thanks that does help! As I am filtering through my locations on my map I was wondering if there would be a quicker way than creating three different custom annotations? I have showed how I am filtering my annotations above. Any guidance would be great

Comment: I might be wrong, I'll recheck the docs later, but I believe the MGLPointAnnotation you are using is a sort of 'simple-case' or 'easy-mode' annotation for when you want something quick and simple marked on the map. For anything more involved, like varying the look or behavior of the annotations, you need to subclass MGLAnnotation. Hopefully I'm wrong but my gut says otherwise. I'll post again when I get a chance to check MGLPointAnnotation in the Mapbox API docs.

Comment: Yay looks like I was wrong! This example on the Mapbox site allows changing the views with MGLPointAnnotations. https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/annotation-views/ They use a funny partial coordinate for the reuseIdentifier but you would use some strings relevantly your use case.

Comment: @Magnas but to add custom properties to the annotation, like you did in your example, such as `image` and `uuid`, one almost must (if not, strongly should) subclass `MGLAnnotation` and ignore `MGLPointAnnotation` altogether, correct?

Comment: @sconewolf - Yes to ignoring MGLPointAnnotation but, more correctly (in the example above), what we’re doing is subclassing NSObject and making our class conform to the MGLAnnotation protocol. As mentioned here https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.6.2/Classes/MGLPointAnnotation.html My above comment is a bit misleading to be honest but the intent was there :)